Ground plane connection to screen
Assuming that I have a quarter-wave monopole for roughly 1GHz, mounted roughly 15' above ground, with a lightning suppressor connected via an N-type sealed with self-amalgamating tape.
I have a convenient perforated stainless steel disc of somewhat larger diameter than the wavelength which I believe would make a good groundplane, however the centre hole is oversize (20 rather than 16mm).
Would I be better off getting a washer TIGed into the middle, or fabricating a sufficiently-strong plastic adapter?
In the either case, to what extent does the antenna characteristic change as the conductivity/insulation of the connection varies, e.g. due to salt-laden wind?

Plastic or metal? I think in order to answer that question, we need more information about the antenna. Please edit your question and add a photo of the antenna.

@MikeWaters Plastic or metal /what/? And I can hardly provide a photo until after I've made it, which is why I'm asking for advice...

I thought that you already had the antenna, which is what I wanted a photo of. How do you plan to feed it? A drawing would be helpful.

You should definitely arrange to connect the ground screen to the body of the connector. If you can have a suitable washer tig welded to the screen, and screw the connector tightly into this, that will be ideal.
The ground screen or counterpoise only works if the RF current can flow out into the screen. If it's not connected, like if you use a plastic washer, it won't do anything (since it lies almost on an equipotential contour, it won't have any current). Instead the whole length of coax becomes the counterpoise, and because it's $>>\lambda/4$ it causes a) pattern break-up and b) VSWR peaks in random places, all depending on the length and arrangement of the coax.
Here are the two cases side by side.


One further thing to consider - depending on your application - is that the pattern of a monopole on a circular groundplane is not ideal for terrestrial communication. The antenna gain on the horizon is just under 0 dBi, not 2 dBi, and it drops fast below the horizon. It's not symmetrical like a dipole would be.
If you have access to a machine shop, a better configuration would be a $\lambda/4$ tube or sleeve hanging down over the coax, instead of the ground screen. Something like this:

The classic "groundplane" design with four wires bent down at about 60 degrees is also good.

Thanks for that, most useful and I think sets a very high bar that any better answer will have to beat. The radiation pattern is important in this case since at least over the next few weeks what I'm looking at is ADS-B with an emphasis on overhead (i.e. rather than distant) traffic: I'm currently using 3/2 lambda to reasonable effect but am getting shadowed by a building. The Wp "Ground plane" article is of little use on this specific point citing a US government publication which is no better: since I am by no means an expert in this area I don't feel competent to edit it.

Great! You can improve the overhead coverage by bending the top half of the monopole over at 90 degrees. This makes it almost omnidirectional (except for polarisation mismatch).

I think I could usefully learn to use nec2c, which looks like some of the more accessible software of that type. However I'm in a fairly good position since I can fit a 2-3m mast to the side of a building to take the antenna above obstructions leaving it relatively accessible, and also since it's ADS-B I've already got positioning information from each contact which allows me to do a polar plot of actual (as distinct from predicted) coverage (examining the frequency being used by each contact already proves to be interesting...).
